# How to set default and auto_now value for django datetime model field

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I want to set a default DateTime for my Django model that will be used in querying data from google fit api. Since this field will be empty in the beginning, the default value will allow for the first query and the auto_now will keep updating as more queries are made. Django seems not to allow both auto_now and default as arguments. Could anyone please assist with a workaround I could use to achieve this?

models.py

```
class GoogleStep(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='googlestep', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starttime = models.DateField(null=False)
    endtime = models.DateField(null=False)
    steps = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    last_sync = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('-starttime',)
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want: so the first time you construct a `GoogleStep` `last_sync` should be something different than the timestamp?

Comment: I want to be able to a set default date to fill the `last_sync` field to perform the first query to google fit rest api when I initialize the model e.g 2010-01-01. After which the field will be updated by `auto_now=True` and perform future queries from the now updated datetime

Answer (score 3):

```
last_sync = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
```

Comment: refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield, `auto_now` must be boolean.